# Why is quixotic pronounced as it is?

Tags: pronunciation, loanwords, literary-english, spanish, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Since "quixotic" was coined with Don Quixote as its basis, why is it pronounced "kwicks-OTT-ick" when it should by rights/origin be pronounced "Key-HO-tick"?

It even sounds more onomatopoeiatic the latter way, as it resembles in its sonorous qualities "chaotic," which suits the subject.

Or is trying to make sense of English pronunciation a quixotic quest?

Comment: “Sonourous”? “Onomatopoeiatic”?  I know words that remind me of those, at least somewhat, but not in the way you would use them. What do you mean?

Comment: "Sonourous" was a typo; the other is a neologism, whose origin and meaning should be obvious.

Comment: I wouldn't say the onomatopoeia is relevant - just a happy accident. I haven't ever heard it said "kwicks-OTT-ick". Where does this happen?? DOES it even happen?

Comment: That is the pronunciation you will find if you look it up - unless you happen to run across something different than me. I have only heard it pronounced that way. How have you heard it pronounced? The way I proposed, or...???

Comment: @nxx, /kwɪkˈsɒtɪk/ is indeed the standard pronunciation. I have heard a few people pronounce it /kiːˈ(h)əʊtɪk/, but these were people who had never actually heard the word used in conversation, but knew of its origins. Also, the more standard adjectives for ‘onomatopoeia’ are _onomatopoeic_ and _onomatopoetic_ (earlier _onomatopoietical_), but not _onomatopoeiatic_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Perhaps [*quijotesque*](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=quijotesco) would work better then.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Since when do you have /əʊ/ instead of /oʊ/? :)

Comment: @tchrist, oh yeah—getting my phonemic and phonetic transcription mixed up here. Let’s just call it broad phonetic RP. :-þ

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet Perhaps I am one of those that simply pronounces it based on knowing its origin. Thinking of it now, I'm not sure if I've ever heard it pronounced! Is /kwɪkˈsɒtɪk/ perhaps an American pronunciation and /kiːˈ(h)əʊtɪk/ British? Can someone point me to pronunciation sources?

Comment: @nxx, the OED has /ks/ for both BrE and AmE (it actually lists both). I've never seen a dictionary list the /ho/ version, even as an alternative, though it does of course exist. (I knew the word before I knew its origin, and I always found it to be cognitively somehow, intangibly and ineffably, connected to ‘quizzical’ until I learnt whence it came).

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet Thanks. Does anyone know of anywhere that cites the /kiːˈ(h)əʊtɪk/ form as correct/acceptable?

Comment: My high school teachers all pronounced it as "kee-ottick", never what I consider to be the British pronunciation of quixotic as shown in the dictionary.

Comment: @nxx in America I have only ever heard it pronounced "kwicks-OTT-ick" by family, friends, news reporters, et al.

Comment: Nothing to do with *quick-as-a-tick*?

Comment: Why do you think that in English a word must be pronounced as in Spanish?

Comment: Do you pronounce 'Paris' the French way? 'when it should by rights/origin be pronounced' is an argument that usually needs throwing out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be dialect issue. Its not a word that comes up much in daily conversation, but the few people I know who use it pronounce it closer to your second (your supposedly "correct") way. More like KEY-hot-ick (emphasis on the first syllable, short o in the middle). However, there are comments below to the effect that your first pronounciation is reported as the "correct" one in the OED, and is understood as such in the UK.

The people I have heard use it are American Midlands dialect speakers (both Northern and Southern varieties). I suppose its possible that your dialect area (from your user info, I'm guessing [California English?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_English)) tends to use the more normal Anglicized version.

Probably the reason for that first reported usage is that it is the pronunciation an English speaker would naively expect for that assemblage of letters, in the absence of any other information. The most common word starting with "qui" is "quick", which is pronounced with the same "kwi", and an "X" in English usually produces a "ks" sound. So if you didn't know the word derived from the name of a character in a Spanish novel, you'd expect it to be pronounced your first way, not in a Spanish-influenced way.

Comment: Oddly enough, the original word has an IPA /x/ in it, not /ks/.  Try saying it *that* way and people will offer you a tissue.

Comment: I've spent over half of my life in my native California, but have also lived briefly in New York, Montana, Alaska, Oklahoma, Idaho, Missouri, and almost a dozen years in Wisconsin. I can't recall just where I heard people say it the unaware-of-the-origin way, though.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Standard English is with /ks/ not /x/.  Spanish, the other way around.

Comment: Well, I'm not saying I've **never** heard the pronunciation you report. However, it has almost always been from people new to the word. After all, that is the pronunciation one would expect for that assemblage of letters in English without hearing anything otherwise.

Comment: The OED says the word can *only* have an English X not a Spanish one (though it does allow that Americans may use their own  style of T, sounding more like a British D). That (i.e. OPs first example) is certainly the way I have heard it.

Comment: I (British) have _only_ ever heard the "quick-sottic" pronunciation and never the other. I have associated this with the fact that up to forty or fifty years ago, everybody who didn't know Spanish (which was nearly everybody in the UI) pronounced the title as if it was English; in fact they did so with most foreign names they came across, except perhaps French ones.

Comment: Interesting. The OED is clearly incorrect here wrt American usage (I guarantee you, that's how I hear it), but the two comments above seem pretty definitive that its a dialect issue. I'll change the answer.

Comment: `"X" in English usually gives you an "sk" sound` - I believe you meant "ks"?

Comment: As an aside, to go with the other comments:  Chicago suburbs, I learned the word more like "kicks-ottic".  Dropped the "u" sound entirely.

Comment: "Dialect" is totally the wrong word when talking about bookish terms like this one.

Comment: @tchrist: but how was Spanish pronounced back when *Don Quixote* was written? The Spanish letter 'x' was originally pronounced /ʃ/ (*sh*; [see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_Spanish_coronal_fricatives#Historical_evolution)), and it still is in Basque.

Comment: @PeterShor It was pronounced  /ʃ/  at that time. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Spanish_language#Modern_development_of_the_Old_Spanish_sibilants) in English or a different article [here](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reajuste_de_las_sibilantes_del_idioma_espa%C3%B1ol) in Spanish which has a nice [chart](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reajuste_de_las_sibilantes_del_idioma_espa%C3%B1ol#/media/File:Reajuste_sibilantes.png).

Answer (score 11):

/'kwɪksət/ is clearly an anglicization of the Spanish spelling.
It's equally clear that such spelling pronunciations have always been very common.

This one, in particular, can be seen in action at the very end of
 [Canto 13, Stanza 10 of Byron's *Don Juan*](http://users.compaqnet.be/cn127848/byron/don-juan/014.htm)
   (a title, incidentally, pronounced /dan'dʒuwən/ by the author, as the poem makes clear)

> Redressing injury, revenging wrong,
>      To aid the damsel and destroy the caitiff;
>   Opposing singly the united strong,
>      From foreign yoke to free the helpless native: --
>   Alas! must noblest views, like an old song,
>      Be for mere fancy's sport a theme creative,
>   A jest, a riddle, Fame through thick and **thin sought**!
>   And Socrates himself but Wisdom's **Quixote**?

Note the rhyme:  *wrong - strong - song* alternating with *caitiff - native - creative*,
and ending in a couplet, with its rhyme boldfaced above. In this couplet,
*Quixote* has to be pronounced in **two** syllables, not three,
**and** the last two syllables  rhyme with *thin sought*.

I.e, **/'kwɪksɔt/**. And from there to /'kwɪksət/ is no distance at all in modern English.

Comment: I couldn't begin to identify the specific components relevant here, but might it not also be that *quixotic* in some way reflects conventional/natural Anglophone prosody better than *Quixote?* And might we not be more ready to anglicize a derived adjectival form than a proper noun? (I think it's already partly "ours", since we're using English grammar to generate the derived form! :)

Comment: Of course. The history of everyone's exposure to a word as rare as _quixotic_ is bound to involve the written word, and thus English spelling. And people (particularly kids) who read books using words like _quixotic_ are apt to be the ones who learned the spelling and pronunciation rules in school. And in any event, the histories are different from one person to another, and no linguistic fact has only one source. Variation is a fact about anything living, like human language.

Comment: I trust you realise that Byron's "Don Juan" is a satire.

Comment: So was _Don Quijote_. So is _The Daily Show_. So what?

Comment: Actually, for Byron I suspect it was only a near-rhyme, and the vowel was /ˈkwɪksoʊt/, which the OED has as a variant. The use of /ɔː/ here (for a perfect rhyme with *thought*) isn't very natural in English spelling.

Comment: And why on earth does Byron not say *"thin and thick sought"* so as to better rhyme with *Quixote*? Checking online, he does ... you get versions with both adjective orders. Apparently somebody misprinted it and the bad version has been copied extensively: *"thin and thick"* can be found in Google books from 1827, and *"thick and thin*" from 1833.

Comment: @PeterShor Unless _thought_ for Byron himself was actually /θoʊt/ as well. Truth be told, I don’t know if /oxt/ → /oht/ → /ɔːt/ went through a paenultimate stage /oʊt/ or /oʊht/ or something like that (thought it must still have been somehow distinguishable from plain /oʊt/ as in _smote_, to remain separate from it), but it doesn’t seem entirely unlikely.

Comment: @Janus: There are definitely historical cases, like the *loin/line* and *mare/player* mergers, when vowels have merged and then separated (so they presumably didn't merge in everybody's speech, or in all dialects). Looking through *Don Juan*, mostly Byron rhymes *thought* with words like *caught*, *brought*, *taught*, but there are quite a few places where he rhymes it with *boat*, *float*, *coat* (as well as once where he rhymes it with *lot*). So if *thought* and *coat* was just a near-rhyme, Byron thought it was a fairly good one.

Answer (score 3):

I've often wondered about the pronunciation of this word.  Where I live in New England, we pronounce any Spanish word that has an X, such as "Mexico,"  in the anglicized version, unless we are speaking in Spanish.  For that matter, when we refer to Cologne, Germany, we don't say "Köln, Deutschland," either, unless we are speaking in German.  So why would we consider saying "Kee-hot-ic?"

My hunch is this:  We all know the Spanish pronunciation of "Don Quixote" as "Don key-ho-tee" from having heard the name pronounced in story-telling, or in the musical, "Man of la Mancha."  So perhaps some of us think we ought to be consistent and also use the Spanish pronunciation for the adjective. But that makes a strange amalgam, because Spanish adjectives don't end in "ic." The actual Spanish adjective is "quijotesco."

So, if we are going to use the English adjective form, then I think we should be consistent and use the English pronunciation.

Comment: You can read a good bit more about this matter [here in this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/190617/2085).

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have covered the bases on *quixotic* quite well, I think. I just want to note here that *quixotic* isn't the only Spanish-derived word containing the letter string *qui* that (at least some) British English speakers pronounce in a very un-Spanish way.

In the United States, children are taught in elementary school about the Spanish conquistadors, who explored (and of course conquered) large areas of the New World during the very late 1400s and the 1500s—and the only pronunciation I have ever heard used here in the United States for the word *conquistador* is *kunkeestuhdor*, with the accent on the *kees* syllable.

But as this video of Procol Harum [performing its song "Conquistador"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Cfzg3_WhLM) in 1977 demonstrates, Gary Brooker, the band's (English) lead singer, pronounces the word *kunkwisstuhdor*, with the accent in the *kwiss* syllable. This, it seems to me, is entirely consistent with pronouncing *quixotic* as *kwiksottik* with the accent on the *sott* syllable.

Indeed, if we accept the three letters *qui* in Spanish as consistently receiving the pronunciation *kwi* (with a short *i* sound) in certain forms of British English, it seems to me that pronouncing the following *x* in *quixotic* as *ks* rather than as *h* follows as a matter of course, given the strangeness (to the mouth of an English speaker) of pronouncing the *h* sound immediately after a short *i* sound. In English we have several words that involve pronouncing an *h* immediately after a long *e* sound (*beehive*, *knee-high*, *freehold*, and *hee-haw*, for example), but none I can think of that involve a short *i* immediately followed by an *h* sound.

For that reason, I would expect an English speaker attempting to pronounce *frijoles* either to try to match the Spanish pronunciation with something like *freeholeez* (with the accent on the *ho* syllable) or to keep the *i* short and pronounce the word something like *frijoleez* (with the accent on the *jo* syllable) or *frijolz* (with the accent on *jolz*).

Comment: Yes, I remember "Conquistador" by Robin Trower and his mates. I always got a chuckle out of how the singer (forget his name) pronounced it, and wondered, "didn't one of the other blokes know the right pronunciation, and were they afraid to correct him, or what?" I guess they (Brits) are a whiter shade of paleface than we Americans.

Answer (score 1):

The word is pronounced "kwiksawtick" because it is an english word that obtains only its etymology from the name of a character from Spanish fiction. In spanish, someone who is quixotic in nature is referred to as being "quijotesco", not "quixotic". Spanish speakers use the former word. For that reason, quixotic is an english word that merits the anglicized "ks" pronuciation of the "x".

Answer (score 1):

An old episode of BBC's QI claims that the [kee-ho-tay] pronunciation of "Quixote" is incorrect as well.

https://www.comedy.co.uk/tv/qi/episodes/17/6/

"The correct pronunciation is 'Don Qui-Sh-Otay', because in the book the character speaks in old Castilian."

By extension, "quixotic" should be pronounced: [kee-sho-tik]. (Or [quiche-ottik], if you prefer.)

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find other sources to back this up. QI's research team has a respectable reputation, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer is in the error in your own question:

> It even sounds more onomatopoeiatic the latter way ("Key-HO-tick), as it resembles in its sonorous qualities "chaotic," which suits the subject.

It doesn't. The pattern of Quixotic is the same as chaotic and exotic

Chaotic - /keɪˈ**ɒtɪk**/ > /kwɪkˈ**sɒtɪk**/; exotic - ᵻɡˈ**zɒtɪk**/