# Connotations of "quixotic"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, adjectives, connotation

Would you say *quixotic* has more of a positive connotation or more of a negative connotation?

The [definition for *quixotic* given by Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quixotic) is:

> hopeful or romantic in a way that is not practical
>
> 1. foolishly impractical especially in the pursuit of ideals; especially :  marked by rash lofty romantic ideas or extravagantly chivalrous action
> 2. capricious, unpredictable
>
> [. . .]
>
> - **Synonyms**: *idealist, idealistic, quixotical, romantic, starry, starry-eyed, utopian, visionary*
> - **Antonyms**: *clear-eyed, clear-sighted*

Given that dictionary entry, it seems like *quixotic* can be interpreted in either of two ways:

- positively (ambitiously idealistic)
- negatively (unrealistic and not grounded in reality).

Which of those two possible connotations of *quixotic* is considered the more correct one for this word?

In other words, if someone were described as quixotic, would that be considered a good thing or a bad thing?

Comment: From my perspective as a native American English speaker, the word "quixotic" has a negative connotation.  Namely that Quixote was a "fool" and he was "rash."

Comment: Whose definition is that? Please supply a suitable attribution.

Comment: The definition came from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quixotic).

Comment: The answer is yes, as @tchrist points out in detail. Yes, it can have a positive or negative connotation.

Comment: Quixote wasn't a fool. Possibly insane, though.

Comment: In order to help you pin down which connotation of Quixotic dominates, let us ask ... did this person also describe you as apt to "[tilt at windmills](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/tilt_at_windmills)"? :)

Comment: @DanBron I was considering using the word to describe a project I was working on. I think that "idealistic", "ambitious", and possibly "foolishly unrealistic" are accurate ways to describe it (and I view that as a good thing), but didn't want to pick a word that would be considered negative or insulting when describing my own work.

Comment: @Allen "So, I have this project ... it's kinda *Quixotic*, but not, you know, full on *tilting-at-windmills*"?

Comment: @DanBron Even more specifically I was considering naming the project "Quixotic". So people would see the word and instantly judge the project based on their thoughts on the connotation of the word.

Comment: @allen, if it's a video game with Quixotic elements, I'd say go for it. Otherwise, I'd personally hesitate.

Comment: "From my perspective as a *native American* English speaker" - which tribe? Quixote tribe?

Comment: If you aren't concerned with the negative connotations in "foolishly unrealistic" then I certainly wouldn't worry about quixotic.

Comment: It's very positive on a Scrabble board!

Comment: *Ahum.* (And yes, I've had "quixotic" in my name for a *very* long time; I didn't change it just for this question.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## On the *quixotic* — and the *Quijote*

Is *quixotic* positive or negative, you ask. An easy enough question to ask, aye.

But to answer? To answer is something else. For it is . . . ***complicated***.

That’s because a tale as rich as [*El ingenioso hidalgo don Quijote de la Mancha*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Quixote) cannot be potted into a single sentence, nor sentiment.  It does not admit a simple yes or no answer.  If you take only one of them, you break it. You must accept them both.

But the novel itself does admit an inescapable interpretation, one that this posting will at length provide before its end.

I would first take issue with the senses provided by the current online Merriam-Webster dictionary. Earlier versions were better.  Although [Dr Johnson’s dictionary of 1755 did not include *quixotic*](http://johnsonsdictionaryonline.com/?page_id=50&whichLetter=Q), by just three-quarters of a century later [Noah Webster’s 1828 dictionary](http://1828.mshaffer.com/d/search/word,quixotic) did so, providing this simple, honest definition that is as true today as it was centuries ago:

> a. Like Don Quixote; romantic to extravagance.

Fast forward almost a century to [*Webster’s Revised Unabridged Dictionary* of 1913](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=quixotic&use1913=on) and we find the entry expanded to the following:

> a. Like Don Quixote; romantic to extravagance; absurdly chivalric; apt to be deluded. Feats of quixotic gallantry." *Prescott*.

A half-century following that edition came the monumental [*Webster’s Third New International Dictionary of the English Language, Unabridged* of 1961](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webster's_Dictionary#Webster.27s_Third_New_International_Dictionary_.281961.29), a groundbreaking ‘masterwork of scholarship’ in lexicography never before seen in North America — nor since: the current M-W holds no candle to it. In the W3 we find the entry for *quixotic* given as:

> **quix·ot·ic** `\(ˈ)kwik¦säd·|ik, ‑ät|, |ēk\` *also* **quix·ot·i·cal** `\ə̇kəl, |ēl\` **:**  *adj* [*quixote* + *‑ic* or *‑ical*] idealistic and utterly impractical, *esp* **:** marked by rash lofty romantic ideas or chivalrous action doomed to fail  〈～ as a restoration of medieval knighthood ―M.R.Cohen〉   **syn** see ɪᴍᴀɢɪɴᴀʀʏ

<sub>(Sorry about all that gibberish pseudo-pronunciation that nobody can understand and which makes no sense anyway; that’s what the book has.)</sub>

Beyond that entry, other related entries in *Webster’s Third* include *quix·ote, quix·ot·i·cal·ly, quix·o·tism, quix·o·tize,* and *quix·o·try*.

I do not know that the W3 much improves on the previous editions’ versions; though more complete, it may overreachingly water down the actual meaning of the word, not recognizing that the original sense is still extant.

Let us therefore turn to an historical dictionary instead, the one that has no peer. The OED defines *quixotic* as:

> ### **quixotic** `/kwɪkˈsɒtɪk/`, *a.* (*sb.*)
>
> Etymology: f. **Quixote** *sb.*
>
> **1.** Of persons: Resembling Don Quixote; hence, striving with lofty enthusiasm for visionary ideals.
>
> - **1815 J. Adams** *Wks.* (1856) X. 157, ― I considered Miranda as a vagrant, a vagabond, a Quixotic adventurer.
>
>   **1857 Hughes** *Tom Brown* i. i, ― This family training··makes them eminently quixotic.
>
>   **1896** *Spectator* 7 Mar. 336 ― Any one can exceed, but few can be really Quixotic.
>
> **2.** Of actions, undertakings, etc.: Characteristic of, appropriate to, Don Quixote.
>
> - **1851 Gallenga** *Italy* 131 ― A daring that would seem almost quixotic.
>
>   **1874 Green** *Short Hist.* x. 719 ― A quixotic mission to the Indians of Georgia.
>
>   **1876 Emerson** *Ess. Ser.* ii. vii. 175 ― All public ends look vague and quixotic beside private ones.
>
> **b.** *pl.* as *sb.* Quixotic sentiments.
>
> - **1896** *Spectator* 7 Mar. 337 ― If··our Quixotics seem foolish or extravagant.
>
> Hence **quiˈxotical** *a.*; **quiˈxotically** *adv.*; **quiˈxoticism** = **quixotism**.
>
> - **1850** *Fraser’s Mag.* XLII. 482 ― No Quixotical redresser of wrong.
>
>   **1862** *Sat. Rev.* XIII. 660/2 ― A mathematician who··Quixotically endeavoured to cure him.
>
>   **1882** *Athenæum* 23 Sept. 410/1 ― The symbol of his noble quixoticism.

And, since *quixotic* is necessarily defined in terms of *Quixote*, the OED defines *Quixote* as:

> ### Quixote `/ˈkwɪksət/`, *sb.*
>
> Also **7** **-ot**, **8** **-iot**, **9** **-otte**.
>
> Etymology: The name of the hero of Cervantes’ romance (see **Don** *sb.*<sup>**1**</sup> <sup>**c**</sup>), = Sp. *quixote*, now written *quijote* `/kiˈxote/` a cuisse.
>
> An enthusiastic visionary person like Don Quixote, inspired by lofty and chivalrous but false or unrealizable ideals.
>
> - **1648** *Merc. Prag.* No. 1. A ij, ― The Romance’s and Gazetta’s of the famous Victories and Exploits of the godly Quixots.
>
>   **A. 1658 Cleveland** *Gen. Poems*, etc. (1677) 112 ― Thus the Quixots of this Age fight with the Windmils of their own heads.
>
>   **1786–7 Bonnycastle** *Astron.* i. 17 ― There are Quixotes and pedants in every profession.
>
>   **1811 Jefferson** *Writ.* (1830) IV. 164 ― What these Quixottes are clamoring for.
>
>   **1896** *Spectator* 7 Mar. 337/1 ― Where the more sober thinker fails, the Quixote is often of service.
>
>   *Comb.*
> - **1800 Mrs. Hervey** *Mourtray Fam.* IV. 41 ― Quixote‐like, going to fight when he had no occasion.
>
> **b.** *attrib.* passing into *adj.* = **quixotic**.
>
> - **1708 Ozell** tr. *Boileau’s Lutrin* iv. (1730) 209 ― A weak Defence for Quixiot kings.
>
>   **1757 Lady M. W. Montagu** *Let. to C’tess Bute* 7 July, ― The Quixote reputation of redressing wrongs.
>
>   **1782 H. Walpole** *Lett. to M. Cole* 14 Feb. (1846) VI. 160 ― My diet-drink is not all of so Quixote a disposition.
>
>   **1810 Bentham** *Packing* (1821) 198 ― Our Quixote Sheriff.
>
> Hence **ˈQuixote** *v. intr.* (also with *it*), to act like a Quixote.
>
> - **1702 Vanbrugh** *False Friend* v. i, ― When you··are upon your rantipole adventures, you shall Quixot it by your self for Lopez.
>
>   **1803 Jane Porter** *Thaddeus* (1826) I. vi. 131, ― I will not be the first to tell him of our quixoting.

To chase the last reference, the one where it says “see **Don <sup>1 c</sup>** ”, the OED provides this at that entry:

> ### Don /dɒn/, *sb.* <sup>1</sup>
>
> Etymology: a. Sp. *don* :– L. *domin-um* <sup>[sic: that’s the accusative; should be *dominus* in nom. sg. or even *domine* in the vocative, since that’s how it is often used. ―tchrist]</sup> master, lord.
>
> **1.** A Spanish title, prefixed to a man’s Christian name.
>
> **c.** [. . .] **Don Quixote**, the hero of a Spanish romance by Cervantes, who, from his attempt to be a knight-errant as described in the books of chivalry, has become the type of any one who attempts to do an absurdly impossible thing or to carry out an impossible ideal; also attrib.; hence, **Don Quixote** *v.*, Don Quixotism: see also ***quixotic***, etc.
>
> - **1674 [Z. Cawdrey]** *Catholicon* 18 ― The furious zeal of persons Don-Quixotted in Religion.
> - **1734 Fielding** *Don Quixote in England* Introd., ― The Audience, I believe, are all acquainted with the Character of Don Quixote and Sancho. I have brought them over into England, and introduced them at an Inn in the Country.
> - **1870 D. G. Rossetti** *Let*. 15 Mar. (1965) II. 817 ― He is a complete Don Quixote in every way.
> - **1900 A. Conan Doyle** *Gt. Boer War* x. 167 ― His long thin figure, his gaunt Don-Quixote face.
> - **1902** *Pall Mall Gaz.* 4 Jan. 6/3 ― This Don Quixote of a society has made an assault upon the most solid of windmills.

So there you have it.

It means resembling the titular Don himself, and **all that that entails**. It means all those things, but most importantly it means resembling “an enthusiastic visionary person like Don Quixote, inspired by lofty and chivalrous but false or unrealizable ideals.”

That’s a lot of denotation — far more than a simple thumbs-up or thumbs-down is ever going to be enough to characterize.

If you are just soliciting opinion, then this is not a good format for doing that.  It would just devolve into a list question full of anecdotal connotations, which could not be substantiated, ranked, nor selected as a single correct answer.

### On pronunciation

No doubt thanks to the award-winning 1965 musical, *Man of La Mancha* and its unforgettable songs, the noun use of that word, *Quixote*, is now most apt to be given in the Spanish pronunciation in today’s America, so `/kiˈxote/` as the OED provides, albeit in monoglots with the alien `/x/` converted to a native `/h/`.  The Anglicized pronunciation of *Quixote* would therefore be `[kʰiˈhoʊɾɪ]`, and that is how it is most often heard in America today. (The runner-up is *Donkey Hody*. :)

See also [Why is quixotic pronounced as it is?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/143475). There seems to be some degree of variation in how present-day English-language speakers pronounce *quixotic* itself. This is probably due to the comparative rarity of the word making it one most speakers have never heard said aloud, only read. There may also be some interference, especially in North America, stemming from an active or passive knowledge of the Spanish pronunciation of the Don’s name as described in the previous paragraph.

Although the OED does not (yet?) attest *quixotesque*, a word calqued on the Spanish *quijotesco* described below, this form can be found here and there on the internet, where it used as a synonym for *quixotic*, especially one with Noah Webster’s original sense of being like Cervantes’ titular hero.

Being a Spanish-speaker myself, I’ve always been a trifle uncomfortable with the English spelling-pronunciation of *quixotic*, since I know that it is based on a misunderstanding.  The *x* in *Quixote* was never a `/ks/` even when the novel was first penned; it meant `/ʃ/` at that time.

When during the 15<sup>th</sup> and 16<sup>th</sup> centuries, all the Spanish sibilants shifted dramatically (as explained in [English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Spanish#Modern_development_of_the_Old_Spanish_sibilants) and [Spanish](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reajuste_de_las_sibilantes_del_idioma_espa%C3%B1ol)), that *x* became phonemic `/x/` (which in Spain is realized as phonetic `[χ]` before a back vowel, and in Mexico phonetic `[h]` anywhere). Consequently, the Don found himself respelled to modern *Quijote*, using the modern *j* to represent `[x]`. (The Mexicans resisted this orthographic realignment, which is why they insist on spelling their country *México* rather than *Méjico*, the latter being the way it is spelled in modern-day Spain to thereby match the actual pronunciation of the word.)

So if I felt particularly daring, or if I were writing to a Spanish-speaking audience who already knew the Spanish word *quijotesco*, or simply because I were stricken with a donnish fit of *quijotería* :), then I just possibly **might** write *quijotesque* in English, giving it an English pronunciation of `/ki(h)oˈtɛsk/`.

But then even fewer people would know what I was talking about than if I wrote *quixotic*.

---

### What’s a *cuisse*?

The OED finishes its etymology of *Quixote* saying that in Spanish it is “now written *quijote* **a cuisse**”. But what’s a *cuisse* — and how does it have anything to do with the Don?

Some of you might know *cuisse* as ‘thigh’ in French, but that is not what it means here. Rather, it is that particular piece of armor which protects the thigh.  The OED gives this entry for the term:

> ### cuisse, cuish `/kwɪs/`, `/kwɪʃ/`.
>
> Forms: *pl.* **4** **quysseaux**, **‑ewes**, **5** **cusseis**, **cussues**, **qwysshewes**, **5–7** **cushies**, **7** **cushes**, **6–9** **cuisses**, **8–9** **cuishes**; *sing.* **5** **cusshewe**, **cusché**, **7** **cush**, **9** **cuish**.
>
> Etymology: In 14th c. *quyssewes*, *cuissues*, a. OFr. *cuisseaux*, *cuisiaux*, pl. of *cuissel* = Ital. *cosciale*, L. *coxāle*, f. L. *coxa* hip, Ital. *coscia*, Fr. *cuisse* thigh. In Eng. the *‑ewes*, *‑ues* of the plural being reduced to *‑ies*, and at length to *‑es*, the latter has been confounded with the plural ending in *fish-es*, etc., and a singular *cuish*, *cuisse* formed. The etymological sing. would be *quissel*, or *quissew*.
>
> *pl.* Armour for protecting the front part of the thighs; in *sing.* a thigh-piece.

The reason this is interesting is that the modern Spanish word *quijote* `/kiˈxote/`, which in Old (and older) Spanish was *quixote* `/kiˈʃote/`, really does mean a thigh-piece of armor. If you trace it back far enough, the English and the Spanish come from the same place. Castilian — by which I mean Spanish — borrowed the word from Catalan, where it was *cuixot*, pronounced `/kʷɨˈʃɔt/`. This comes from the Latin *coxa* meaning hip. So [Spanish *quijote*](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=quijote) and English *cuisse* came from the same place, albeit via different routing (ours came via Norman French).

Why the middle-aged country gentleman from dusty La Mancha should have chosen, upon taking up the mantle of a knight-errant, to rename himself for the piece of armor that defends the vulnerable thigh from harm is itself a fascinating point of contemplation, but not especially germane to the current question.  It is, however, central to how he conceived of himself — which is.

It is also part of a common thread of his choosing to see the world as he **would** that it were, not as it was: he romantically renamed his tired old nag [*Rocinante*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocinante), and he sweetly renamed a plain-looking farmer’s daughter [*Dulcinea*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dulcinea), surely as dulcet a name as they come.

---

### It all comes down to that *ingenioso hidalgo*, the Don himself

The Spanish noun *quijote*, taken from the Don, is [per the RAE](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=quijote) an

> Hombre que antepone sus ideales a su conveniencia y obra desinteresada y comprometidamente en defensa de causas que considera justas, sin conseguirlo.

Freely translated, he’s a man who places his ideals in front of his own convenience, selflessly committing himself to the defence of those causes he considers just, without managing to succeed in this.

The Spanish adjective corresponding to English *quixotic* is *quijotesco*, and that is the word with the sense that for me *quixotic* carries in English: it’s about being like don Quijote, just like Noah Webster told us nearly two centuries ago.

And *quixotic* still means that. It’s about taking up a just cause for the sake of noble ideals without regard to personal hardship, adversity, or even practicality or likelihood of success. It’s about trying to do what’s right even when you know you can never prevail.

Is that a positive thing or a negative thing?

That’s a very personal decision, but I for one consider it in the most positive of all possible lights, howsoever doomed it may be.  Nothing great was ever achieved by aiming low.

Some battles are worth fighting for, fighting for with all our heart and mind and soul and body, even all the while knowing that in the end we must ultimately fall in that battle, that we must in the end inescapably fail forever.

### After all, isn’t that what *life itself* is?

The lyricist for the musical stunningly captured all of this when he famously wrote:

> ## *The Impossible Dream (The Quest)*
>
> *To dream the impossible dream,
>
>   To fight the unbeatable foe,
>
>   To bear with unbearable sorrow,
>
>   To run where the brave dare not go.
>   
>
>
>   To right the unrightable wrong,
>
>   To love pure and chaste from afar,
>
>   To try when your arms are too weary,
>
>   To reach the unreachable star.
>   
>
>
>   This is my quest, to follow that star:
>
>   No matter how hopeless, no matter how far.
>
>   To be willing to give when there’s no more to give,
>
>   To be willing to die so that honor and justice may live.
>   
>
>
>   And I know if I’ll only be true
>
>             to this glorious quest
>
>   That my heart will lie peaceful and calm
>
>             when I’m laid to my rest.
>   
>
>
>   And the world will be better for this:
>
>   That one man scorned and covered with scars,
>
>   Still strove with his last ounce of courage
>
>   To reach the unreachable star.*

That song, you will note, ends on a very high note, musically reminding us of ***ad astra per aspera***.  Now **you** tell **me**: does that sound positive or negative?

There is only one possible answer that allows life to continue, and that must surely be that  it **must** be positive. Otherwise we should all just give up right now and die, since we know how our story ends. And we mustn’t do that.

**Life itself is *quixotic:*** we cannot prevail in the end.  In the end, all hopes must fail, and fall we surely shall.

But that does **not** mean we should not **try**!

Indeed, it is knowing that we must ultimately fail that gives us fools the most reason to rush in where angels fear to tred: to try all the harder, to run all the farther, to aim all the higher —  ***that the world might be better for this.***

Comment: A friend of mine from Manchester once described something to me as being quite 'keyotic', a word I utterly failed to comprehend. Wasn't until she gave the connection with the Don himself that I realised what she'd meant, and that I had never heard anyone before apply the Spanish-based pronunciation (with Eschree loss of the h, no less) to the adjective. She, in her turn, had only ever really come across the word as a 'book word', so she'd made up her own pronunciation to match the etymology.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I’ve always been nervous about saying *quixotic* because of hearing *Quijote* millions of times more often in Spanish than in English. Their adjectival form is *quijotesco*, with potential for wickedly sounding a bit like the start of *¡Qué jodido …!*  It occurs to me that I’d best explain what the OED means when they say *“a cuisse”* at the end of their *Quixote* etymology, since here *cuisse* (< Fr.) is *thigh **armor*** not the thigh itself. But do note that Castilian *quijote* < Catalan *cuixot* thigh armor-piece (< L. *coxa, ‑ae* hip), **not** < Catalan *cuixe* thigh.

Comment: Oy. I feel like I deserve an upvote just for reading that all the way through, but since that's not how the world works, +1 for you instead. :)

Comment: @tchrist Thanks for the answer. The OED could be added the following for quixotic : A. Trollope "The way we live now" : Mr. Broune did not think that an offer so quixotically generous as this should be accepted.

Comment: @DuchampGérardH.E. Is that from the OED3?

Comment: No. By the way there is another one in the same book : Even the large sum of which he had become so unexpectedly possessed would not have gone far with him in such a quixotic object as that

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Congratulations! The tale of your Mancunian friend has inspired me to the *quijotería* of including an explanation of, and justification for, saying `/ki(h)oˈtɛsk/`.

Comment: That's not just an answer. Its a bloody midget thesis 0_0

Answer (score 7):

Neither the positive nor the negative definition you provide for *quixotic* stands on its own: it’s the combination of the two that gives the word its unique meaning.  Something *quixotic* is simultaneously ambitiously idealistic and hopelessly unrealistic.  It’s not *quixotic* if it isn’t both.

Answer (score 2):

Context, context, context!  It all depends on the point of view of the person using the term.  They could be admiring someone for doggedly fighting the windmills despite the overwhelming odds against winning, or they could be assigning the label of "fool" to someone who should just give up.  As tchrist says...it's complicated.

Comment: How about a comment, down-voter?